# How to set a border to a cell in a column that is not empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a border script that checks if column "A" is not empty and then paints a border around the entire row, within this script I also have a thick border around non empty cells in a specified columns. I am running into issues now where its not removing all the borders each time the script is called in the menu item.

```js
function setborders() {
  var menu = [{
    name: "Borders for nonempty cells",
    functionName: "borders"
  }];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Set Borders", menu);
}

function borders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var numsheets = ss.getNumSheets();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s]
    var r = ss.getActiveRange();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:V1000");
    var values = range.getValues();
    var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex();

    for (var i = 0; i < allsheets.length; i++)
      if (['Current Sales', 'Pending Orders', 'Subcontract Orders', 'Partial Shipped', 'Quotes', 'Archived Sales'].indexOf(allsheets[i].getName())) {

        if (sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue()) {
          range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
          for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0]) { // Only for non-empty A column cells
              sheet.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
            }
          }

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0] && values[i][14]) {
              sheet.getRange("O" + (i + offsetRow) + ":O" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
            }
          }

          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0] && values[i][18]) {
              sheet.getRange("S" + (i + offsetRow) + ":S" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
            }
          }
          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0] && values[i][19]) {
              sheet.getRange("T" + (i + offsetRow) + ":T" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
            }
          }
          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0] && values[i][20]) {
              sheet.getRange("U" + (i + offsetRow) + ":U" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
            }
          }
          for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i][0] && values[i][21]) {
              sheet.getRange("V" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code (after discussion):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:V1000");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex();

  if(s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1).getValue()) {
    range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0]) { // Only for non-empty A column cells
        ss.getRange("A" + (i + offsetRow) + ":V" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] && values[i][19]) { // Only for non-empty T column cells (in addition to the above condition for A column cells)
        ss.getRange("T" + (i + offsetRow) + ":T" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thin border is applied for non-empty A column cells, and additional thick border - for non-empty A and T column cells.

Comment: it is working however the last non blank cell in the column has the bottom border thin

Comment: I guess, thin border is due to the next row, where T cell is blank. If so, we can do 2 loops: the first one - for thin border painting, and the second one - for thick...

Comment: How would you break it into two loops?

Comment: One more issue I am running into is another script file that sorts the sheet is not moving the cell border to follow the row when being sorted.

Comment: You are right about sorting: it does not take format into account. Be sure to do formatting **after** sorting.

Comment: So I would need to set this script file up to run after another script file.

Comment: Looks like I need a way to make this run after another script file has completed. I have searched for methods to do this but as far as i can see maybe a sleep function will do this?

Comment: I think that scripts synchronization may be a separate question topic, if you can not run one script at the end of another one. Consider the alternative to use **conditional formatting** (fonts and background colors, but not cell borders). This way is much easier to implement.

Comment: updated script, with issue of not removing all cell borders. can anyone see why this is happening?